# What the first one means in hangfire recurringjobs?

Tags: jobs, hangfire, abp

In Hangfire Recurring Jobs:

```cs
HangfirePeriodicBackgroundWorkerAdapter<BackgroundJobWorker>.DoWorkAsync
```

What the first one means? Can I delete it?

It seems to be executed every five seconds? Will it consume too much resources?

Thanks very match!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZJDv.png

This task is added by the `AbpBackgroundWorkersHangfireModule` module, from the ConfigureServices method.

```cs
    public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        context.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(HangfirePeriodicBackgroundWorkerAdapter<>));
    }
```

To disable this task, you must override the module method.

```cs
public class MyAbpBackgroundWorkersHangfireModule : AbpBackgroundWorkersHangfireModule
{
    public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
    {
        //base.ConfigureServices(context);
    }
}
```

And replace `DependsOn(typeof(AbpBackgroundWorkersHangfireModule))` by `DependsOn(typeof(MyAbpBackgroundWorkersHangfireModule))`.

**Warning: I do not know the effects that this can cause.**